# Seeking website to do geoprocessing online?

Tags: geoprocessing, software-recommendations, online

Is there a website in which I can do geoprocessing online?

I know there are a lot of sites that allow the visualisation of your data online or some basic map-making, but I need something more...
Kind of like a free online GIS.

For example, go on a website, draw a polygon and extract the land cover inside.

Comment: There are lots of sites that can provide specific results for specific geoprocessing tasks, like USGS StreamStats for determining watersheds. If there's something in particular you're after, you may want to narrow your question down.

Comment: Is the USGS StreamStats only for the USA?

Comment: Yes, just for the USA.

Comment: Would WPS services be in scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with [Google Earth Engine](https://earthengine.google.com/).

Answer (score 1):

What about Scribble map. This one requires you to pay to be able to use it but I did play it around and the only thing allowed me to export to kml and then convert it to shapefile...It's neat but doesn't have the geoprocessing you need...

https://www.scribblemaps.com/

just hit Create a free map button and
then just draw what you want and be sure to save the map 
then do export it in kml.  If this is not what you are looking for then I would google it "Similar to Scribble Maps" or "Create a free maps" then there are a few interactive maps that you might want to play it around...

Answer (score 0):

The [USDA Geospatial Data Gateway](https://gdg.sc.egov.usda.gov/GDGOrder.aspx) allows you to download GIS datasets by drawing a polygon around your area of interest. Not quite geoprocessing, but it will allow you to accomplish the task listed in your example.

You'd probably get more responses if you specify what type of operations you need to perform and for what geographic area(s).

Comment: The type of operations I need to perform is exactly like the one in my example i.e. get the land cover from a watershed. Like the [Tabulate Intersection](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/tabulate-intersection.htm) tool in ArcGIS.

And for the geographic area, it needs to be world wide.

Comment: Acquiring the world wide land cover dataset is not a problem. I often use the [ESA/CCI dataset](http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/). So I would just need the geoprocessing service.

Comment: @Nehas in that case, have you tried downloading the data from their site by defining a location on the map? http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/profiles.php

Comment: I need to define the zone freely by drawing a polygon. Not just a point.

Comment: Are you apposed to downloading an open source GIS program and working it out on your own processor?

Comment: It's not ideal, but I'm not opposed. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The USDA Geospatial Data Gataway can be pain sometimes so I tried to avoid it and sometimes it's not what you wanted  but it's good for imagery you want to download at that site @Jyler

Comment: @Nahas [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) is considered to be one of the most robust and user friend FOSS GIS platforms.