# How can I change the labels in the console output in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: labeling, google-earth-engine

This is the second part of my edited two part question (first part [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182078/how-can-i-have-the-percentage-instead-of-the-frequency-in-google-earth-engine)).

So I used the following script:

```js
// define the var
var Catchment = /* color: 98ff00 */geometry;
var landcover = ee.Image('users/roynahas/ESACCI-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P5Y-2010-v161_RECLASS').select('b1');
// Clip the image to the polygon geometry and add it to the map
var landcover_clip = landcover.clip(Catchment);
var sld_intervals =
'<RasterSymbolizer>' +
 '<ColorMap  type="intervals" extended="false" >' +
 '<ColorMapEntry color="#FFFF00" quantity="1" label="Agriculture"/>' +
 '<ColorMapEntry color="#00FF00" quantity="2" label="Grassland and Shrubland"/>' +
 '<ColorMapEntry color="#008000" quantity="3" label="Forest"/>' +
 '<ColorMapEntry color="#00FFFF" quantity="4" label="Flooded"/>' +
 '<ColorMapEntry color="#FF00FF" quantity="5" label="Urban areas"/>' +
 '<ColorMapEntry color="#808080" quantity="6" label="Bare areas"/>' +
 '<ColorMapEntry color="#0000FF" quantity="7" label="Water"/>' +
 '<ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="8" label="Permanent snow and ice"/>' +
 '</ColorMap>' +
'</RasterSymbolizer>';
Map.addLayer(landcover_clip.sldStyle(sld_intervals), {}, 'IGBP classification styled');
// Print out the frequency of landcover occurrence for the polygon.
var frequency = landcover.reduceRegion({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  geometry:Catchment,
  scale:300
});
print('landcover frequency', frequency.get('b1'));
```

To get the following console output:

[image]

**My question : How can I change the labels in the console output in Google Earth Engine?**

Instead of "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", and "8", I want to have "Agriculture", "Grass and Shrubland", "Forest", "Flooded", "Urban areas", "Bare areas", "Water", and "Permanent snow and ice".

Comment: You will need to share your private asset ('users/roynahas/ESACCI-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P5Y-2010-v161_RECLASS') if you want others to reproduce your results.

Answer (score 3):

To demonstrate an solution, I first modified your example to use a public landcover asset (NLCD 2011) and an explicit geometry:

```
var Catchment = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-109.6435546875, 41.98399427093563],
          [-109.6435546875, 41.68111756290652],
          [-109.171142578125, 41.68111756290652],
          [-109.171142578125, 41.98399427093563]]]);
var landcover = ee.Image('USGS/NLCD/NLCD2011');

// Print out the frequency of landcover occurrence for the polygon.
var frequency = landcover.reduceRegion({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  geometry:Catchment,
  scale:300
});
var landcover_frequency = ee.Dictionary(frequency.get('landcover'));
print('landcover frequency', landcover_frequency);
```

You can rename the "labels" (dictionary keys) by creating a lookup table and using the `ee.Dictionary.rename()` method:

```
// Lookup table based on https://www.mrlc.gov/nlcd11_leg.php
var landcover_lookup = ee.Dictionary({
  "21": "Developed, Open Space",
  "22": "Developed, Low Intensity",
  "31": "Barren Land",
  "52": "Shrub/Scrub",
  "71": "Grassland/Herbaceous",
  "90": "Woody Wetlands",
  "95": "Emergent Herbaceous Wetlands"
});

// Print landcover frequencies with modified labels.
print('landcover frequency', landcover_frequency.rename({
  from:landcover_lookup.keys(),
  to:landcover_lookup.values()
}));
```