# Exporting each image from collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-1, synthetic-aperture-radar

I am trying to export each image in a filtered stack of Sentinel-1 images and cannot seem to get it right.

[Think link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204366/extracting-landsat-time-series-data-by-polygon-using-google-earth-engine/204482#204482) suggests using `imageCollection.map()` and a custom function (such as a geometric clip).

```
// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-63.0, 9.2, -63.1, 9.3]);


// Load the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection.
var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD');


// Filter by metadata properties.
var IW_H = sentinel1
  // Filter to get images with VV and VH dual polarization.
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
  // Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
  // Filter IWs to get High res.
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution', 'H'))
  // Filter IW-Highs to get 10m res
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters', 10));


// Filter to get images from different look angles 
var DescCollection = IW_H.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));


var ClipFunc = function(iImage, geom) {
  var iClip = clip(iImage, geom);
  return(iClip);
};


imageCollection.map(ClipFunc(DescCollection, roi));
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Export.image.toDrive` is a client-side function, and you cannot call it from a server-side function (the one you are mapping over), so you have to do it all in the client side. I have a repo where you can find a bunch of useful functions: https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor
There is a function to export all images from an ImageCollection to the Drive cloud.

```js
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-63.0, 9.2, -63.1, 9.3]);


// Load the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection.
var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD');


// Filter by metadata properties.
var IW_H = sentinel1
  // Filter to get images with VV and VH dual polarization.
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
  // Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
  // Filter IWs to get High res.
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution', 'H'))
  // Filter IW-Highs to get 10m res
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters', 10));


// Filter to get images from different look angles 
var DescCollection = IW_H.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(DescCollection, 'Folder', 
                {scale: 10, 
                 region: roi.getInfo()["coordinates"], 
                 type: 'float'})
```

You can find the complete code in [here](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/blob/319b26d005d7ee12fd024ff90f281e641299e590/batch#L80) and the documentation [here](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki/Batch)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've seen this code and attempted it. I'm not very knowledgeable with GEE or javascript. My Chrome browser is going unresponsive and asks to be killed. I'm not sure if it's running (and grinding down my machine) or if something is amiss. 
I will try with a very limited collection as a test. 
cheers

Comment: @ThrushJacket I use mainly the Python API, so I am not sure if this works properly, I'll check it right now. I think the *region* parameter may cause the error

Comment: @ThrushJacket I tested it, works fine just as it is. Try with less images, as it is a client side, it can hang your browser.

Comment: This is now running and outputting images, however, the region parameter is acting odd. Instead of clipping to the region I've defined (a bounding box), it's outputting 4 separate TIFFs of varying sized subsections of the image (that combine to make the full scene).  I've defined region above your function:
`// Create a geometry representing an export region`
`var region = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-62.85, -9.21, -63.14, -9.49]);`

Comment: If your export image gets too large GEE will export it in separate shards you can merge after downloading.

Comment: I've sorted it out, I was inadvertently overwriting the call to my bounding box (by originally naming it "region"). Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe I get the error: Cannot read property 'toDrive' of undefined. I use batch.ImageCollection.toDrive(sm_des_66, 'test', {scale:100})

Comment: thanks @tillKadabra, I've updated the answer: `batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive`

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe now i get `"batch" is not defined in this scope.`. I have read rights to your repository and i use `var tools = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')` https://code.earthengine.google.com/d9bebc4523ebcb3de85b72fa9e1bc6e3

Comment: You are importing the repository into `tools` variable but trying to use `batch`.. see: https://code.earthengine.google.com/dcee89acbe86bca49ce72605a9f5a7fe (line 90 makes the difference)

Comment: Thank you this helped. Although, for some reason I had to comment out the following line, otherwise I receive the following the errors after: region: roi.getInfo()["coordinates"], object.name is not a function
Invalid GeoJSON geometry: –, 

https://code.earthengine.google.com/78c134c4cd859e2f411356ed273895cc

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to apply Rodrigo E. Principe's algorithm. The GEE states the following phrase:

"Cannot read property 'toDrive' of undefined"

I tried to run the algorithm for two different imageCollections, but the same error occured in both. The first was Rodrigo's Dataset (SENTINEL-1 data), exactly as stated in his answer above. The second trial was over precipitation data. This later algorithm is presented below.

```
 var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');
 var Municipios =  ee.FeatureCollection("ft:1YvIAGUsonY9NVnSJETwkWjj_UO_Db0zqSHx2WHIs");

print(Municipios.limit(20), 'Municipios 500x500m2');


var roi = Municipios.geometry().dissolve().bounds();

print(roi, 'roi');

print(roi.getInfo()["coordinates"], 'get info coordinates from roi');

// Display the sample region.
Map.centerObject(roi, 5);
Map.addLayer(ee.Image().paint(roi, 0, 2), {}, 'ROI');



// Load a pre-computed Landsat composite for input.
var precipitation = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY')
    .filterDate('1981-01-01', '2019-12-31')
    .select('precipitation')
    .filterBounds(Municipios.geometry().dissolve().bounds())
    .map(function(image) {
      // Data to .
      return image.set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
    });

Map.addLayer(precipitation, {'bands': ['precipitation'], min:0, max:2000}, 'collection');




batch.ImageCollection.toDrive(precipitation, 
                'Precipitation_daily_data', 
                {scale: 1000, 
                 maxPixels:5000000000,
                 region: roi.getInfo()["coordinates"], 
                 type: 'float'})
```

I would like to state that I paid attention to the directory into which the dataset would be downloaded in my Google Drive ('Precipitation_daily_data'), so to garantee beforehand that it would exist, as states in the batch manual cited by Rodrigo.

Comment: Apparently, the error appeared due to a misuse of the property Download from the batch object. I am somehow managing to operate the precipitation dataset by replacing "batch.ImageCollection.toDrive" to "batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive".

Comment: sorry Philipe and all who had the same problem. I didn't see this comment before. I've now corrected the answer, you were right about the code.