# Sentinel-1 missing data gap in adjacent acquisitions

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, sentinel-1, synthetic-aperture-radar

Some months ago I posted [Export each image from a collection in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248216) about exporting Sentinel 1 scenes from a collection and was successful with help from [Rodrigo Principe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/23470/rodrigo-e-principe).

I now have a new region of interest, which sits on the overlap between 2 scene footprints (sequential images in descending orbit). When I make a mosaic of the 2 scenes I get a small no data gap and lack of alignment between the 2 images:

```
// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-62.67, -8.31, -63.25, -8.85]);
var zoomPoint = ee.Geometry.Point([-62.35, -8.06])

// Load the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection.
var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
.filterBounds(roi);


// Filter by metadata properties.
var IW_H = sentinel1

// Filter to get images with VV and VH dual polarization.
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))

// Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))

// Filter IWs to get High res.
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution', 'H'))

// Filter IW-Highs to get 10m res
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters', 10));

// Filter to get images from different look angles
var col_desc = IW_H.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));

// Spatially mosaic the images in the collection and display
var col = col_desc.mosaic();
var colVV = col.select(0)
Map.addLayer(colVV, {min:-17, max:-3}, "VV");
Map.centerObject(zoomPoint, 20);
```

What am I missing?  Are these scenes not acquired sequentially?
https://code.earthengine.google.com/ca7a4b585f1600b771a2de07c8e75792

Comment: do you want to download every image of `col_desc` or just the mosaic you made clipped with `roi`?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I would like to download every (mosiaced) image in col_desc.  In the time since my post I just exported the north and south scenes separately, with the intention of merging them myself.  However, there is a small missing data gap (1-3 pixels) between the 2 scenes when I do this.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you trying to do, you can download every image of the collection or mosaic ALL into ONE image (the mosaic). Also, I don't get what you mean by 'north and south scenes'

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the confusion. I'm attempting to filter the sentinel collection that coincides with my roi, but this falls on the region between two acquisitions. Consequently, when I try to filter and export, I'm only getting the more recent acquisition (the South scene in descending orbit) which is only half my roi. I need to merge both scenes that coincide with my roi (the North and South acquisitions) then clip and export. I tried doing separately (previous comment) but there's a no data gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more recent version of this question has been answered here:
[Sentinel-1 missing data gaps between two images GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356727/sentinel-1-missing-data-gaps-between-two-images-gee)

To quote that answer:

> Guido Lemoine gave a clear answer on your developer forum thread:
>
> Yes, this is due to the terrain correction step. Original GRD scenes
> are contiguous, and broken up at the 25 second slices (for IW), see
> the image timestamps. The last line of slice N is exactly adjacent to
> the first of N+1.
>
> Terrain correction is a bit tight on sampling at scene boundaries,
> which often causes a 1 pixel gap.
>
> This would be solvable if you would first do slice assembly in s1tbx
> and then TC the assembled orbit strips. This takes loads of memory,
> however, esp. since s1tbx is not very efficient in memory management.
> SAR is just a series of time samples in range arranged in azimuth, the
> "scene" concept is actually somewhat old fashioned, inherited from
> "GIS" concepts.
>
> But given that 80% of the GEE crowd seems to be still concerned with
> downloading "scenes", it's probably not a good idea to create
> mega-size assembled orbit strips.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-earth-engine-developers/9qdJ9IUFdWE/vmof4jB4AAAJ

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you don't need `ExportCol` function because you want to download just 1 image (the mosaic). Try this:

```
// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-62.67, -8.31, -63.25, -8.85]);

// Load the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection.
var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
.filterBounds(roi);

// Filter by metadata properties.
var IW_H = sentinel1

// Filter to get images with VV and VH dual polarization.
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))

// Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))

// Filter IWs to get High res.
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution', 'H'))

// Filter IW-Highs to get 10m res
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters', 10));

// Filter to get images from different look angles
var col_desc = IW_H.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));

// Sort in descending order (latest first)
var desc = col_desc.sort("system:time_start", false)

// Mosaic
var mosaic = ee.Image(desc.mosaic())

// Check if it is what you need..
Map.addLayer(mosaic,{}, "mosaic")

// Export
var task = Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mosaic,
  region: roi.getInfo()["coordinates"],
  scale: 10,
  description:'COMPLETE', 
  folder: 'COMPLETE', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'COMPLETE',
  maxPixels: 1e13
})
```

Comment: Hi Rodrigo. Really sorry I am explaining this so poorly. I am trying to extend my original question (linked) to a scenario where the ROI overlaps the seam of 2 acquisitions. Thus, I need to query the 2 scenes that overlap my ROI (each day), merge them (with mosaic?), then crop to my ROI. I wish to do this for each orbit pass (whole collection), thus I'm attempting to do this for every scene pair over my ROI (n=30ish)-  essentially looping through the pairs for each day. This is why I suspected I needed to somehow add a mosaic function inside the ExportCol function you've written.

Comment: Incidentally, I've spoke with a friend working on Sentinel data over the whole of Kenya and he has had a similar issue dealing with mosaic images output from GEE, where noData gap exists between sequential acquisitions in an orbit. He indicated there been a fair amount of discussion on this in the GEE developers group

Comment: I downloaded the image to see the results and have not seen the no-data gap, but if there is an issue there, I think we cannot do anything about it from *the Client Side*

Comment: Hi Rodrigo. Thanks again for the time spent on this. Looks like there are some raster alignment issues between acquisitions- if you zoom right into the seam. [link to screenshot](https://s7.postimg.org/8enqrg21n/Capture.png)
I've managed a work around for now- exporting the 2 acquisitions separately and merging them myself.  Not sure why this is resolved when exported but appears in the visualization from script.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying the `blend()` function. It seems to work in case the `mosaic` doesn't do the job.
As GEE docs say:

> blend(top) overlays one image on top of another. The images are blended together using the masks as opacity. If either of images has only 1 band, it is replicated to match the number of bands in the other image.

Hope that helps