# Sentinel-1 missing data gaps between two images GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1, missing-data

I am trying to export a Sentinel-1 mosaic with the code below. I keep getting this missing data gap between the two images. Even when I export the images separately, and mosaic them myself in ArcGIS, I still have this problem.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/91fea33548352ade6dd961ed3d34d883

```
var start_date = ee.Date('2019-08-01');
var finish_date = ee.Date('2019-08-15');
var orbit = 'ASENDING';

// Get the VV collection.
var collectionS1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    //.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', orbit))
    .filterDate(start_date, finish_date)
    .filterBounds(polygons);

 // Get the VV collection.
var collectionVH = collectionS1.select('VH');

var VH = ee.Image(collectionVH.median());

Map.centerObject(polygons, 7);
Map.addLayer(VH, {min: -25, max: 5}, 'VH', true);

//Import Tool
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

// Change Folder Name

var folder = 'GEE_EXPORT';


// Download Collections
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(collectionVH, folder,  
        {name: 'VH_'+orbit+'_'+'{id}',
               scale: 10,
              region: polygons,     
                fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
                  maxPixels: 1e13,
              type: 'float'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guido Lemoine gave a clear answer on your developer forum thread:

> Yes, this is due to the terrain correction step. Original GRD scenes
>   are contiguous, and broken up at the 25 second slices (for IW), see
>   the image timestamps. The last line of slice N is exactly adjacent to
>   the first of N+1.
>
> Terrain correction is a bit tight on sampling at scene boundaries,
>   which often causes a 1 pixel gap.
>
> This would be solvable if you would first do slice assembly in s1tbx
>   and then TC the assembled orbit strips. This takes loads of memory,
>   however, esp. since s1tbx is not very efficient in memory management.
>   SAR is just a series of time samples in range arranged in azimuth, 
>   the "scene" concept is actually somewhat old fashioned, inherited from
>   "GIS" concepts.
>
> But given that 80% of the GEE crowd seems to be still concerned with
>   downloading "scenes", it's probably not a good idea to create 
>   mega-size assembled orbit strips.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-earth-engine-developers/9qdJ9IUFdWE/vmof4jB4AAAJ

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Very helpful! Just wanted to make sure it wasn't something I go fix easily.