# Applying visualisation parameters to all images in image collection when exporting to drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to apply an image visualisation to all the images from a filtered image collection, and export the images to Google Drive using the GEE Javascript API.

I can do the export fine, but I just end up with binary black/white images that aren't useful, so I need to add a {min:-20, max:1} visualisation to each image in the collection either before or during the export job.

Here is the code I'm using to try and achieve that, adapted from the answers to [Export each image from a collection in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248216/export-each-image-from-a-collection-in-google-earth-engine).

```js
// Import batch tools from fitoprincipe
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

// Define a rectangular image region for filtering the collection and exporting images
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-73.85413391074309, -47.41730172316857],
          [-73.85413391074309, -47.47117019964287],
          [-73.72641784628996, -47.47117019964287],
          [-73.72641784628996, -47.41730172316857]]], null, false);

// Load the Sentinel-1 Image Collection and filter by properties          
var IW_H = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
        .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
        .filterBounds(geometry)
        .filterDate('2017-07-01', '2017-07-20')
        .select('VV');

// Filter to get images from different look angles 
var DescCollection = IW_H.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));

// Define visualisation parameters for the exported Sentinel-1 images
var visParams = {min: -20, max: 1};

// Export all images in collection to test folder in my drive
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(DescCollection.visualize(visParams), 'test', 
                {scale: 10, 
                 region: geometry, 
                 fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
                 formatOptions: {
                  cloudOptimized: true
                  }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.visualize()` is an `ee.Image` method, so you must map over the collection to apply visualization to each image in the collection before exporting.

Replace your export code chunk with this:

```js
// Map over the collection to convert VV data to vis-gray visualization images.
var DescCollectionVis = DescCollection.map(function(img) {
  return img.visualize(visParams).copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames());
});

// Export all images in collection to test folder in my drive
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(DescCollectionVis, 'test', 
                {scale: 10, 
                 region: geometry, 
                 fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
                 formatOptions: {
                  cloudOptimized: true
                  }
                });
```

For further reference on mapping a function over a collection, see this developer guide section: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/getstarted#mapping-what-to-do-instead-of-a-for-loop