# Batch exporting image collection from GEE with visualization

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to batch export GeoTIFFs from the ERA5-Land-Hourly dataset from a single day to Drive, using the [geetools](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor) repo in the Code Editor, with a visualization and cropped to a defined AOI. I tried to export the images by applying the visualization in the manner described in the answer to [Applying visualisation parameters to all images in image collection when exporting to drive](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342475), but the images that get exported are either corrupted or in black/white instead of the palettes specified. Here is my code:

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

//Create geometry variable
var xMin = -122.29169;
var yMin = 37.41229;
var xMax = -122.20243;
var yMax = 37.55015;
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(
[
[xMin, yMin],
[xMax, yMax]   // max x and y
 ]
);

//create filtered image collection
var startDate = ee.Date('2017-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2017-01-02');
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY").filterDate(startDate, endDate).select('temperature_2m');

//create visualization parameters                                  
var visParams = {
  min: 250.0,
  max: 320.0,
  palette: [
    "#000080","#0000D9","#4000FF","#8000FF","#0080FF","#00FFFF",
    "#00FF80","#80FF00","#DAFF00","#FFFF00","#FFF500","#FFDA00",
    "#FFB000","#FFA400","#FF4F00","#FF2500","#FF0A00","#FF00FF",
  ]
};

//apply visualization to image collection
var datasetVis = dataset.map(function(img) {
  return img.visualize(visParams).copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames());
});

//Export image collection to Drive with visualization applied
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(datasetVis, 'ERA5-data', {
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry
})
```

Comment: I have tried the code but didn't get any corrupted or black and white image. Images are in .tif format and are colored as they should be. I opened the images in qgis. Which software did you use to open the images?

Comment: I had converted the GeoTIFFs to PNGs using IrfanView to view them, and they were in black and white. Some of them were corrupted when trying to view in different photo-viewing applications. But they are colored accurately in QGIS as you mentioned. Is there a way to batch export them as PNGs from QGIS?

Comment: You can use pyQGIS to iterate over the layers and export them to png.