# Clipping MODIS burnt area collection using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, clip, modis, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using the MODIS Burned Area Monthly Global 500m product in GEE. I would like to export the information in a .tiff file for a designated area, which I have imported into GEE as a shapefile. The original code is as follows

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD64A1')

              .filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2020-06-05')); 
  var burnedArea = dataset.select('BurnDate');

  var burnedAreaVis = {

  min: 30.0,

  max: 341.0,

  palette: ['4e0400', '951003', 'c61503', 'ff1901'],
};

  Map.setCenter(30, 50, 6);

  Map.addLayer(burnedArea, burnedAreaVis, 'Burned Area');
```

I have tried to clip the collection to the shapefile using cliptocollection, but it consistently comes up with different error codes.

How do I export a collection such as this to my drive?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to export images within your geometry, you don´t need to clip them. Just specify  the geometry as `region` when exporting.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
image: your_image,
description: 'name_of_exported_tiff',
scale: 500,
region: your_geometry,
crs: 'EPSG:4032' 
});
```

If you want to export the entire collection, the answer to this question may help you. [Export each image from a collection in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248216/export-each-image-from-a-collection-in-google-earth-engine)