# Batch download through GEE Python API?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am having trouble batch downloading all of the individual images within an input collection within the GEE Python API. I know there is a function that is callable within the main GEE API using Rodrigo Principe's tool via

```
     var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')
```

([Export each image from a collection in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248216/export-each-image-from-a-collection-in-google-earth-engine))

but I am having trouble calling this function within Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I can answer this.

You have to install `geetools` for python

> pip install geetools

then, in the code

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
import geetools

collection = ee.ImageCollection('....')

# batch export to Google Drive
geetools.batch.Export.imagecollection.toDrive(
    collection, 
    'Folder', 
    namePattern='{id}', 
    scale=30,
    dataType="float", 
    region=None, 
    datePattern=None,
    extra=None, 
    verbose=False
)
```

The parameter `namePattern` defines the name for each file. You can use any image property, or '{id}' for image id, or {system_date} for the date (formatted by `datePattern`). For example,

```
geetools.batch.Export.imagecollection.toDrive(
        collection,
        ...,
        namePattern = 'S2SR_{system_date}_{CLOUD_COVER}',
        datePattern = 'y-MM-dd',
        ...)
```

so the resulting files will be named:

`S2SR_2019-01-01_96`
`S2SR_2019-01-05_60`... and so on

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you!