# Google Earth Engine Exporting Image Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, landsat, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Google Earth Engine and satellite imagery in general. My goal is to export bands B1-B7 from the [Landsat 8 image collection][2] over a given geometry and be able to visualize each band (or combination of bands) in a jupyter notebook. However, I am only able to export the median of my geometry in order to convert the image collection to an image. How can I export my geometry in a way that doesn't capture the median of each band?

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat 8 SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image input Landsat 8 SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloudmasked Landsat 8 image
 */
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
                  .map(maskL8sr);
                  
var landsat8 = dataset.median().clip(polygon);

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
Map.setCenter(13.534922,-12.350257, 16);
Map.addLayer(landsat8.median(), visParams);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: landsat8,
  scale: 30
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The image that you are exporting is the median of your Landsat collection.

Exporting from earth engine can only be done one image at a time.

You could write a loop in javascript to export each of the images individually inside the loop.

See this answer by Rodrigo Principe on how to do it.

[Export each image from a collection in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248216/export-each-image-from-a-collection-in-google-earth-engine)