# Google Earth Engine: Export image collection to Asset while preserving original scale of individual image's bands

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to export an image collection to the Google Earth Engine's Asset, while preserving the original spatial scale of each individual image's bands.

The [Rodrigo Principe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/23470/rodrigo-e-principe)'s answer to a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248216/export-each-image-from-a-collection-in-google-earth-engine?answertab=active#tab-top) shows how to successfully perform such an operation; the code follows below and in this [GEE code link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0b98ec47f75982d737a96318beabc0fd).
In the example, when setting the parameter 'scale: 10', all the exported image's bands will be resampled to a 10 m spatial scale.

However, the original Sentinel 2 OLI image's bands are distributed in different spatial resolutions (e.g. B2 = 10 m; B5 = 20 m).

*How to export a Sentinel 2 image collection (S2_col) to GEE Asset preserving the original spatial scale of each individual band within an image?*

```
// -- Selected point of interest 
var PoI = ee.Geometry.Point(-52.905090, -28.228550);
// Map.centerObject(PoI, 5);

// -- Region of Interest (ROI) and time span 
var polygon = PoI.buffer(100).bounds();//buffer around the point
var start_date = '2017-01-01';
var end_date   = '2017-02-20';

var criteria = ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.bounds(PoI), ee.Filter.date(start_date, end_date));
var cloud_perc = 60;//Max cloud percentile per scene.    

var S2_col = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
                .filter(criteria)
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', cloud_perc));


var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');//By https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/23470/rodrigo-e-principe
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toAsset(S2_col, 'assetFolder', 
                {scale: 10, 
                 region: polygon, 
                 type: 'float'})
```

Comment: Not sure about the default behaviour of batch.download in the tool, but did you try not setting a scale at all in the arguments? Else you can dig up the code of the batch.download script and alternate the default behaviour of the function such that it retains the original resolution of each band (e.g. not setting a scale in the export function).