# Projection error in Google Earth Engine when exporting 30x30m global image to asset

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image-mosaic

**Context**

I downloaded .tiff files at 10x10 degree tiling (~280 tiles) with a resolution of 30x30m and datatype float. I uploaded each of the 280 tiles to an Earth Engine (EE) asset folder and mosaiced the images to obtain a layer with global coverage. I would like to export this mosaiced layer to an EE asset, so I do not have to run the mosaicing workflow in every script.

After running the code (see below), I open the "Task" ribbon in the EE Code Editor and run the task and specify the crs in the popup window. Exporting the layer with `Export.image.toAsset({...})` and providing `scale` as an argument throws the error :

```
Error: Projection error: Unable to compute intersection of geometries in projections <Projection> and <Projection>. (Error code: 3)
```

When I rerun the export, the error gets thrown at different times each run, e.g. after 1min, 4min, 16min or 25min

**Question**

What does the error mean and how can resolve it to export a 30x30m mosaiced image with datatype float to an EE asset?

**Code**

```
// get image links form parent folder and access nested field containing all info
var agb_assets_obj = ee.data.listAssets(
  'projects/.../assets/GFW_AGB');
var agb_assets = agb_assets_obj.assets;

// Define function to turn asset links into ee.Images
var listImages = function(listElement) {
  return ee.Image(listElement['name']);
};

// create images from asset links
var images = agb_assets.map(listImages);

// turn ee.Images into ee.ImageCollection
var col = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(images);

// obtain scale from (arbitrary) first image of collection
var agb_scale =  col.first().select('b1').projection().nominalScale()

// turn ee.ImageCollection into mosaic
var col_mosaic = col.mosaic();

// export image
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: col_mosaic,
  scale: agb_scale.getInfo(),
  description: 'GFW_AGB_t_ha',
  assetId: 'GFW_AGB_t_ha',
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

**What I tried**

I played around with providing different arguments to the export:

```
// specify scale based on one image of the mosaic: Error: Projection error
// export image
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: col_mosaic,
  description: 'GFW_AGB_t_ha',
  assetId: 'GFW_AGB_t_ha',
  scale: col.first().select('b1').projection().nominalScale().getInfo(),
  crs: col_mosaic.projection().crs().getInfo(),
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

// specify transformation based on one image of the mosaic: Error: Unable to export the unbounded image. (Error code: 3)
var trans = [0.00025, 0, -180, 0, 0.00025, 90]
// export image
Export.image.toAsset({image: col_mosaic,
  //scale: agb_scale.getInfo(),
  description: 'GFW_AGB_t_ha',
  assetId: 'GFW_AGB_t_ha',
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  crsTransform: trans,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
});


// specify region based on footprint of mosaic: Image export successfully after 45mins but does not show up on map when plotted
var trans = [0.00025, 0, -180, 0, 0.00025, 90]
// export image
Export.image.toAsset({image: col_mosaic,
  //scale: agb_scale.getInfo(),
  description: 'GFW_AGB_t_ha',
  assetId: 'GFW_AGB_t_ha',
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  crsTransform: trans,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  region: col_mosaic.geometry()
});
```

I checked some links, e.g. [Google Earth Engine: Export image collection to Asset while preserving original scale of individual image's bands](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411238/google-earth-engine-export-image-collection-to-asset-while-preserving-original), but did not find an answer to this specific error.

Comment: It would be helpful to be able to inspect your assets.

Comment: Thanks @Noel, I put the access to "anyone can read" under this link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-exploratory-spatial/assets/GFW_AGB. The original .tiff files are from here: https://data.globalforestwatch.org/datasets/e4bdbe8d6d8d4e32ace7d36a4aec7b93_0/explore?location=2.212499%2C0.000000%2C2.03

Comment: You have to also share each individual asset, since they're in a folder.  You should be storing these in an image collection instead of a folder.