# Export Image from GEE without dividing the file

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I tried to export my analyzed images from Earth engine with the original resolution of Landsat 30m (scale:30), but the file in my drive was divided into many sub-files. I wonder is there any way to export but don't break the file. My file totally is just 700mb. Here is the source code of mine (https://code.earthengine.google.com/df029fbc1f462d739b93203b1ccd6c54):

```
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0").filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Pakistan'));
Map.addLayer(roi, {color: 'black'}, 'Study Area',1);
Map.centerObject(roi, 8);
// landsat 8
function maskL8sr(image) {
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);

  // Replace the original bands with the scaled ones and apply the masks.
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
      .addBands(thermalBands, null, true)
      .updateMask(qaMask)
      .updateMask(saturationMask);
}
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2022-1-01', '2022-12-31')
    .filterBounds(roi);
var clouds_free = dataset.map(maskL8sr);
var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
};

Map.addLayer(clouds_free, visualization, 'image')
// add NDWI
function addNdwi(img) {
var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B5']).rename('NDWI');
return img.addBands(ndwi);
}
var addwaterMask = function(image) {
   var NDWI = image.select(['NDWI']);
    return image.addBands(NDWI.gte(0.15).rename('NDWI_mask'));
  };
var ndwi = dataset.select(['SR_B3', 'SR_B5'])
.map(addNdwi).map(addwaterMask);


var result = clouds_free.map(addNdwi).map(addwaterMask);
var freq = result.select('NDWI_mask').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());

print(result.count())
print(result.size())
//Map.addLayer(result.count())

/*var visparams = {
  bands: ['NDWI_mask_mean'],
  min: 0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['yellow','darkblue']
};


Map.addLayer(freq_mask.clip(roi),visparams,'Water freq');*/
var freq_mask = freq.updateMask(freq)
var roi_snow = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[73.5135662690601,37.139113335514836],
[70.4154217378101,36.37334070791654],
[69.5255291596851,33.674787599395366],
[71.0636150971851,33.68392991577811],
[72.9972088471851,34.68362148689567],
[73.9640057221851,34.366823955507385],
[74.6781170503101,36.59417260995306],
[73.5135662690601,37.139113335514836]]);
var ndsi  = clouds_free.mean().clip(roi_snow).normalizedDifference(['SR_B3','SR_B6']);                  // snow/ice index
Map.addLayer(ndsi, {min:0.0, max: 1, palette: ['darkred','blue','darkblue']}, 'NDSI image')

var snow_mask = ndsi.updateMask(ndsi.gte(0.0))

var wom_mask = freq_mask.where(snow_mask, 0)
var wom = wom_mask.updateMask(wom_mask)

 var swater = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_4/GlobalSurfaceWater').select('seasonality');
      var swater_mask = swater.gte(10).updateMask(swater.gte(10));
      
 //Flooded layer where perennial water bodies (water > 10 mo/yr) is assigned a 0 value
      var flooded_mask = wom.where(swater_mask,0);
      // final flooded area without pixels in perennial waterbodies
      var flooded = flooded_mask.updateMask(flooded_mask);
//Map.addLayer(wom.clip(roi),visparams,'Water freq exclude snow',0);
//Map.addLayer(flooded.clip(roi),visparams,'flooded',0);
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:flooded.clip(roi),
  description:'f2022',
  scale: 30,
  fileNamePrefix:'2022',
  region: roi,
  maxPixels:1e13
});
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:wom.clip(roi),
  description:'w2022',
  scale: 30,
  fileNamePrefix:'2022',
  region: roi,
  maxPixels:1e13
});
```

Comment: You can look at my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/440595/154371

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your help, I wonder how can we know the dimension of the file ?

Comment: You can explicitly set it when exporting with the `fileDimensions` argument. You got some more code here if you want to dig deeper into this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/360062/154371