# How to calculate forest loss in google earth engine

Tags: change-detection, google-earth-engine

I am using the method outlined in a previous question - [Extracting land cover type in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230774/extracting-land-cover-type-in-google-earth-engine) - to identify habitat type and area with a defined polygon. I would now like to take this information from different years to calculate forest cover loss over time. How is this best achieved? 
I am using google earth engine for this process.

Comment: I think the answer is in this other question.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255879/iterating-over-years-for-features-in-public-feature-collection-using-gee
Code link: [enter link description here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7405deb2901a53729745cea43986e708)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find global forest loss/gain from 2000-2015 in the following raster:

```
var hansen = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015_v1_3");
```

How you can use it is explained in [this Google Earth Engine tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_forest_03).