# Exporting feature collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, nlcd

I am working out the area (in hectares) of a land cover class in the counties of California using google earth engine. So far, I have created a featurecollection that works, but when I try to use the export to table function I get the following error:

**Error: Feature, argument 'metadata': Invalid type. Expected: Dictionary. Actual: FeatureCollection.**

I don't mind if the export is CSV or SHP - whichever is easiest as I will then analyze my data in R/arcpy.

My code is as follows:

```
print('starting...');
// Load a FeatureCollection of US Counties.
var Counties = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2016/Counties");

//Imports NLCD Land Cover Data
var LandCover = ee.Image('USGS/NLCD/NLCD2011')

var cali = Counties.filter(ee.Filter.eq('STATEFP','06'));
Map.addLayer(cali, {}, 'cali');

// Clip the image to the polygon geometry
var LandCover = LandCover.clip(cali);


// Extract the landcover band
var landcover = LandCover.select('landcover');
Map.addLayer(landcover, {}, 'landcover');

// create masks for each class, then covert into area by multiplying by pixel
// area and dividing by class #, then sum reduce over the counties
// then export each as a table (if you can aggregate into one table)
// https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230774/extracting-land-cover-type-in-google-earth-engine

var lc11 = landcover.eq(52);
var mask11 = landcover.mask(lc11);
var pixarea = ee.Image.pixelArea();

var pix2area11 = mask11.select('landcover').multiply(pixarea.select('area')).divide(520000);

Map.addLayer(pix2area11, {}, 'pix2area11');

pix2area11 = pix2area11.select('landcover');
var area11 = pix2area11.reduceRegions({
  collection: cali,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  scale: 30,
});
// Print the first feature, to illustrate the result.
print(ee.Feature(area11.first()));

// Translate feature collection to table with necessary identifiers

area11 = area11.select(['sum', 'COUNTYFP', 'STATEFP']);


print(area11);
Map.addLayer(area11, {}, 'area11');

// Make a feature without geometry and set the properties to the dictionary of area11.
var feature = ee.Feature(null, area11);

// Wrap the Feature in a FeatureCollection for export.
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection([feature]);

// Export the FeatureCollection.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: featureCollection,
  description: 'area11',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
// https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting

print('done');
```

Answer (score 3):

The second argument of `ee.Feature` must be

> **properties (Object, optional):**
>   A dictionary of metadata properties. If the first parameter is a Feature (instead of a geometry), this is unused.

but you are using a `ee.Feature` instead of an `Object` (dictionary). What I understand is that you want to get rid of the geometry and only export the properties. Otherwise you could just export `area11`.

For exporting the collection without the geometries you can do:

```js
// Wrap the Feature in a FeatureCollection for export.
var featureCollection = area11.map(function(feat){
  var nullfeat = ee.Feature(null)
  return nullfeat.copyProperties(feat)
})
```